# Column contains unit ($ sign) that need to be replaced

Tags: r, subset, gsub

I have a few columns that contain a `$` in the value through the excel sheet.

```
 [1] "$5,656.50"  "$3,179.20"  "$1,391.40"  "$2,376.30"  "$1,476.80"  "$712.30"    "$5,327.80" 
  [8] "$3,642.70"  "$1,506.00"  "$7,923.70"  "$4,782.30"  "$1,392.40"  "$229.30"    "$1,106.90" 
 [15] "$1,553.30"  "$3,492.30"  "$4,029.40"  "$1,646.70"  "$6,013.90"  "$19,928.00" "$4,260.60"
```

There are >10,000 rows in this column and R will read it as a character due to the "$".

I tried

```
gsub( "$", " ", thedata$col.with.dollar.signs)
```

to replace the dollar sign with a space, but it didn't work.

Any other ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape the `$` sign with "\\": `gsub("\\$","","$5,656.50")`

Comment: The dollar sign is a special character which you need to esacpe in regular expressions. Or use `fixed = TRUE` instead (which should also be faster)

Comment: You can use `stri_split` function from `stringi` package which works with dollars

Comment: I'd also get rid of commas (assuming you eventually want to coerce to `numeric`) in one call: `gsub("[$,]","",x)`.

Answer (score 0):

This one maybe:

```
substring(thedata$col.with.dollar.signs, 2)
```

For example:

```
vec <- c("$5,656.50", "$3,179.20", "$1,391.40")
substring(vec,2)
#[1] "5,656.50" "3,179.20" "1,391.40"
```